# how to calculate the percentage for different bug severity rating for black-box testing

Tags: manual-testing, bug-severity

I am performing Black-Box testing and I know for certain that different severity has a different rating. So what I'm asking here is that how do I calculate the percentage of the bugs found for that particular test case.

Example: I have a test case with 10 scenarios and 3 of those failed, of the 3, 2 are majors and 1 is minor. Now I'm not sure if I can say that 30% of the scenarios failed since those 3 have different severity rating. So how can I summarized this test case and state how many of the scenarios failed in relevance to their severity.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about that distinction.  I'm not sure what extra value lies in breaking out the failure rate by severity. Instead, I would just report the failure rate as 30% in your sample data

Breaking out severity when reporting on the defects might provide useful information, especially if your exit criteria puts limits on defects by severity classification.

Comment: So what I'm gonna do here is to state the percentage of the scenarios that failed and will state how many of those are majors, minor bugs. would that be an acceptable presentation?

Comment: Acceptable to whom and for what?  Have you considered asking the person who told you to do this what they consider acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I would report this a bit differently. You should report that 3 out of 10 tests failed or 30% failure rate. However the issues found should be reported separately as one issue can cause multiple tests to fail or one test can fail due to multiple issues.

I find that having multiple metric will help you report your issues more accurately.